Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object DocumentApp while trying to open Google doc file
I am trying to open a doc file and replace a value using the simple snippet:
function openFile(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("docId");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("Name of Accountant","ABC");
}

I got to know from this thread that error is due to e-signature that I am using in my doc file. The error looks like this:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property
openById on object DocumentApp.

The table in my doc file, you can find sample file here:

Is there a way that I can open and get the body of the doc file without removing the e-signature from the table? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Here is the doc sample that I am using: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RMCxm0SsqzmsSbx16kTho7GEYOOapoKQbdf0jwNbGMc/edit?usp=sharing

Tried Advanced Google services or Google Docs API?

@TheMaster I think that in the case of OP's situation, your comment will be an answer. How about posting it as an answer?

FWIW, I tried to write a short script today bound to a copy of your doc (having remmed out ALL of your code); the script was based on var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); and I got the error: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getActiveDocument on object DocumentApp..  (queue background music from "Twilight Zone"). I don't have an explanation but this is odd.

@Tedinoz It's a bug and was reported in the issuetracker linked by OP.

You can use the Google docs API to get the data directly using UrlFetchApp or by using  Advanced Google services.
For eg, using Advanced Google services(with identifier Docs), you can get the 4th index's table like this:
function getDocData(){
  const doc = Docs.Documents.get("1RMCxm0SsqzmsSbx16kTho7GEYOOapoKQbdf0jwNbGMc");
  const table = doc.body.content.find(section => section.startIndex === 4).table;
  const row3c2_content = table.tableRows[2].tableCells[0].content[0].paragraph.elements;
  console.info(row3c2_content)
}

To replace text, issue a replaceAllRequest,
const 
  text = 'Name of Accountant',
  replaceText = 'ABC';
Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(
  {
    requests: [
      {
        replaceAllText: {
          containsText: { text, matchCase: true },
          replaceText,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  "1RMCxm0SsqzmsSbx16kTho7GEYOOapoKQbdf0jwNbGMc"
);


You want to replace the value in the cell adjacent to "Name of Accountant" in a given table.
This answer is a far less complex solution as it assumes that you have knowledge of the document AND table beforehand.

function updateAccountant() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var body = doc.getBody()
  var tables = body.getTables()
  //Logger.log(tables)
  var targetTable = tables[0]

  // get the cell values for confirmation
  var leftCell = targetTable.getRow(1).getCell(0);   
  var text = leftCell.getText();   
  // Logger.log(text)  // DEBUG

  var rightCell = targetTable.getRow(1).getCell(1);  
  var text1 = rightCell.getText();   
  // Logger.log(text1) // DEBUG

  // value to update
  var accountantName = "John Joseph Bloggs"
  // update table text
  rightCell.setText(accountantName);
}


TABLE - before

TABLE - after


I thought you got the error Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getActiveDocument on object DocumentApp.. 

I started with a clean document.

Did it have E. signature? Coz that's the main issue.

No. And I had noted that this was an issue with the OP’s file.
